# Examples of $C^1$ differentiable convex functions.

Tags: convex-analysis

Could you please provide examples of convex functions that are differentiable, but their derivatives are not differentiable.

Comment: Here is a nice result for building such functions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143721/about-convex-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f$ as follows:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
 & 2x^2  \text{ if } x \leq 0 \\ 
 & 3x^2 \text{ if } x>0 
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is differentiable with:

$$f'(x)= \begin{cases}
 & 4x  \text{ if } x \leq 0 \\ 
 & 6x \text{ if } x>0 
\end{cases}$$

$f'$ is monotonically increasing, thus $f$ is convex. Yet the second derivative does not exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^2, x\geq 0\\ 
0, x< 0
\end{matrix}\right.$